# iOS iAd Integration Issue With UIToolBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, iad, adbannerview

I am trying to add iAd into my project. The view controller that i am trying to iAd into contains a UIWebView. A UIToolBar is also added at the bottom. Above the tool bar, i have dragged a ADBannerView inside my StoryBoard. This is how it looks like:

[image: ios iad integration]

To show the ads, this is what i have done so far: Added iAd frameWork, created an IBOutLet from AdBannerView named "banner", in viewDidLoad i assigned the delegate to self. Then i added the AdBannerViewDelegate methods and also added the following method:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.banner.bannerLoaded) {
        CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
        CGRect bannerFrame = self.banner.frame;
        contentFrame.size.height -= self.banner.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        self.banner.frame = bannerFrame;
    }
}
```

Well the iAd is properly showing with all the above i have done.

**PROBLEM:** The first time the view is loaded, it shows the ads properly but when i unload and reload the view again, UIToolBar disappears and is covered by the AdBannerView which is shifted below in place of UIToolBar. Can anyone points out where the problem could be and how to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to setting frames in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method. When using auto layout, you shouldn't set any frames. In the storyboard, when you add the addBannerView, give it a height constraint, and spacing constraints to the to sides of the view, and a vertical spacing constraint to the tool bar (the web view should also have a vertical spacing constraint to the top of the add banner view). Delete the viewDidLayoutSubviews method, and it should work properly.

Comment: Removed the viewDidLayoutSubviews method and now its working fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a z-index problem to me, and if this is the case, the solution is quite simple. If you're using Interface Builder, you can use the Document Outline on the left side of your screen to drag and drop views to adjust their z-index. The bottom of the list is the highest z-index and therefore the top on screen view.

Or, if you want to make the adjustments in code, instead of using `addSubview:`, you can use one of the following.

```
[<#(UIView *)#> insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> aboveSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
[<#(UIView *)#> insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> atIndex:<#(NSInteger)#>];
[<#(UIView *)#> insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> belowSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
```

Comment: i am using StoryBoards

Comment: @AJ112 Storyboards use Interface Builder.

Comment: i have updated the image in my question. Can you tell precisely what i have to do in the document outline?

Comment: @AJ112 Right, as I explained in my post, the ad is covering the toolbar because the ad banner is listed below the toolbar in the Document Outline (the left of your screenshot). Drag and drop to switch their order.

Comment: now the banner view is showing below the UIToolBar which means now UIToolBar is covering the Ad Banner View. What to do now?